# How to search the associated model values using 'dusen' gem

Tags: ruby, search, ruby-on-rails-4, indexing

In rails 4.0.2, I am trying to use a search plugin called `dusen`. Using this, I can search same model's values but I am not able to search other(associated) model values. How can I achieve this for single association(has_one / belongs_to) & multi association(has_many) model values?

Reference link:
https://github.com/makandra/dusen

Gem which I am using is `dusen (0.4.10)`

In controller,

```
@query = params[:query] || ""
Contact.search(@query)
```

In model,

```
belongs_to :city, :class_name=>"City"

search_syntax do

 search_by :text do |scope, phrases|
   columns = [:name, :contact_number, :email]
   scope.where_like(columns => phrases)
 end

end
```

Here, It will search only `:name, :contact_number, :email` fields, if i try to add below piece of code then it will show an error like `undefined method 'search_text' for #<Dusen::Description:0xb438a248>`

```
search_text do
  [city.name]
end
```

Please suggest a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model name is 'User', you'd set it up as follows:

```
# User.rb
belongs_to :city, :class_name=>"City"

search_syntax do

 search_by :text do |scope, phrases|
   # namespaced fields to search by.
   columns = ["users.name", "users.contact_number", "users.email", "cities.name"]
   # specify association to City in scope.
   scope.joins(:city).where_like(columns => phrases)
 end

end
```

I hope this helps!